# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when writing to a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write to a model for the first time to use in my view: the first time I write to the model I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Getting error on first write to array:

```
private IAdditionalQuestionsService _service;
private SelectedAdditionalQuestionAnswerModel _model;
private void InitializeController()
{
    _service = GetObject<IAdditionalQuestionsService>();
    //GetPageHeaderText(inst);
    ViewBag.GetPageTitle = "Additional Questions";
}

[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Edit()
{
    Institution inst = _service.GetInstitution(State.GetInstitutionRecordId());
    _model = GetObject<SelectedAdditionalQuestionAnswerModel>();
    _model.AddQuestAnswModel = new List<AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel>();
    GetPageConfiguration1(inst);
    return View(_model);
}

AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel m = GetObject<AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel>();
int c = 0;
foreach (var x in inst.AdditionalQuestions)
{
    foreach (var y in x.AdditionalQuestionAnswers)
    {
        // Error is happening on next line *************
        _model.AddQuestAnswModel[c].QuestionText = x.QuestionText;
        _model.AddQuestAnswModel[c].InstitutionId = x.InstitutionId;
        _model.AddQuestAnswModel[c].AdditionalQuestionId = x.Id;
        _model.AddQuestAnswModel[c].AnswerText = y.AnswerText;
        _model.AddQuestAnswModel[c].IsSelected = false;
        c++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `_model.AddQuestAnswModel[c]` because you never added any items to your list.

Instead of that, create a new object and set its values and then add the item to your list.

Something like this:

```
AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel newItem = new AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel();

//set the values here to newItem

_model.AddQuestAnswModel.Add(newItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're firstly instantiating your list

```
_model.AddQuestAnswModel = new List<AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel>();
```

then you try to access to the first element

```
_model.AddQuestAnswModel[c] // c == 0
```

without adding any element to the list.

Add an element before trying to access to a list by index, or more simple:

```
foreach (var y in x.AdditionalQuestionAnswers)
{
    AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel newObj = new AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel
    {
         QuestionText = x.QuestionText;
         InstitutionId = x.InstitutionId;
         AdditionalQuestionId = x.Id;
         AnswerText = y.AnswerText;
         IsSelected = false;
    };

    _model.AddQuestAnswModel.Add(newObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ir means that there no item in your `_model.AddQuestAnswModel` at the indicated postition, and from your code, I see that `_model.AddQuestAnswModel` has only be initiated with `new List<AdditionalQuestionAnswerModel>()`, so it does not contain items (unless you're doing it in the contructor).

You need to fill it like so :

```
_model.AddQuestAnswModel.Add(item);
```